# Can my mom cosign on my student loan if she already has a HELOC?

Tags: loans, heloc

My mother currently has a Home Equity Line of Credit with her bank for about 40k (I'm not sure of the exact figure but it is around there).

For the school I am planning on attending, I will need to take out a loan of about 30k for the first year alone, and then about 15-20k the following 3 years. In total I will have to borrow somewhere around 90-100k more or less. That's a lot of money. I am aware of the responsibilities involved, and I am confident that if I get into this school I will have a well paying job after graduation.

Of course as a 22 y/o college student I have no credit, and unfortunately I do not have any other family willing or able to cosign for me. I guess what I am worried about is being denied the loan because I need a cosigner and my mother already has her HELOC through the bank. I know her credit is good and she has made every payment on time.

Does anyone have any insight?
Does a HELOC effect your ability to cosign a private student loan?

I would really appreciate any answers as I am trying to get an appointment with my mother's banker but currently I am just left to worry. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's no generic answer to this.  It just depends on whether the bank is satisfied that she can and will pay it off if necessary.

Comment: What will your expected salary be upon completion of this program?  If it is less then 300K/year (starting), I would suggest a different course of action.

Comment: @Pete B. I don't know that I agree with the 300k/year figure but the point is valid for sure. Expected income is a huge factor in this decision.

Comment: Okay, I'll bite @homer150mw.  If a person had no money and wanted to spend 100K on an education what starting salary would they have to make?  Also given is that there is no plan for living expenses during the 4 years.  When you consider that a person could work and attend a state school for most programs and accumulate little or no debt, then (to me) 300K is a good figure when you consider risk and opportunity cost.

Comment: @Pete B. Very few jobs start with that sort of salary so that isn't a very expectation. I would consider a combination of expected starting salary, potential for growth as well as demand for that job.  With excellent demand and growth prospects a starting salary of $80k might be ok where a position with 0 demand a salary of 300k wouldn't be worth spending that much for school. I agree that looking at minimizing the cost is a better course of action regardless.

Comment: No jobs come with that kind of starting salary.  Which is my point.

Comment: @Pete B. My point is depending on the degree it might be justified. Try getting a medical degree without debt. It might be a graduate level engineering degree. To make a blanket statement that it is always wrong to have significant debt for a degree is a bit shortsighted. I agree with you that it is usually a bad idea, just not always.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and for the formatting edit, I wasn't paying much attention last night. Just to clear up a few things, I'm not exactly sure what my estimated starting salary would be. This is an american school with a campus in Japan. My loans would also include living expenses in Tokyo, and my degree would be well regarded in both The States and Japan, which is why there is such a premium price tag. I would have to go into debt no matter the school I choose. I'm also eligible for a few scholarships that will help me out along the way. I know what I'm doing in that regard.

Comment: starting salary right out of school would be realistically 60k/year. Why would you say I need atleast 300k/year to justify 90k in loans?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how close to her limits she is now -- it's entirely up to the bank.

Comment: This is a simple answer but it really is the best answer for the question